# Bootstrap 4 .card-group not applying to cards within columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height, padding

I want to create a card group of 3 cards that each should be 4 columns wide. How do I achieve this and keep .card-group working to make them all the same height?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Card text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your divs that declare the col-md-4 class. Card groups and decks are built to auto size your cards width, and will space them evenly automatically.

Check out the sample block for [groups](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#groups) from the official documentation if you want to see an example.